# What is the difference of running commands in terminal and shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to check if tmux alias exists, when I run command in terminal:

```
$ type -t tmux
```

the result is

```
$ alias
```

But when I put "type -t tmux" in a shell script and run, the result is

```
$ ./test.sh
$ file
```

Why the result is different ?

My test.sh is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

type -t tmux
```

Comment: Aliases are not inherited by child processes. see http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_05.html

Answer (score 0):

Any aliases defined in `.bash_profile` should be read and respected by tmux, but does not read anything in `.bashrc`.

Invoking test.sh is a sub-process, and does not use environment from current process unless you source it
`source test.sh` but that also allows that script to modify current environment.